# SQLite Asynchronous Task and the Wait operator - will Tasks execute in correct order?

Tags: c#, xamarin, async-await, task, sqlite-net

I have a SQLiteAsyncConnection Database with several tables and I want to get the Primary Key back after insert into one of them. My insert looks like this in the Database Model

```
    public Task SaveZoneAsync(Zone zone)
    {
        if (zone.ID == 0)
        {
            return database.InsertAsync(zone);
        }
        else
        {
            return database.UpdateAsync(zone);
        }
    }
```

also in the database model I have this method for getting the last inserted id from a given table.

```
    public async Task<int> GetLastInsertAsync(String tablename)
    {
        int x = await database.ExecuteScalarAsync<int>("SELECT last_insert_rowid() FROM " + tablename);
        return x;
    }
```

In my ViewModel I have this method and plan to pass a Zone object into it to insert into database

```
    public static int AddZoneToDB(Zone zone)
    {
        Task AddZone = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => App.Database.SaveZoneAsync(zone));
        AddZone.Wait();
        Task<int> getID = App.Database.GetLastInsertAsync("Zone");
        getID.RunSynchronously();
        int zoneID = getID.Result;
        return zoneID;
    }
```

and execute it like this

```
int zoneID = MapPageViewModel.AddZoneToDB(zoneToAdd);
```

My question is will the `AddZone.Wait()` in the `AddZoneToDB` method make sure that the `addZone` task is finished running before getting the int from `getID.Result`? Basically trying to make sure I always get the right ID from the correct record. I'm just not sure how `Wait()` and `RunSynchronously()` work together. This is a Xamarin SQLite db in Xamarin.Forms. ID is set as the primary key and to auto increment in the Zone model.

Comment: Just try it out and see. Also try using async/await because it is much easier

Comment: I haven't been able to get my head around how to use async/await very well. You can see I use it a little in the code but I'm sick of having to do so much work figuring out how to make methods async etc. in order to use await.

If you have any really good tutorials about how to use await/async you can point me to that would be very appreciated. The documentation I have found online just seems to leave me more confused.

Comment: I would recommend using async/await *consistently* OR changing your connection type to SQLiteConnection and use synchronous code and wrap it in threads (via task.run or manually created thread instances)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Avoid using `Task.Factory.StartNew` and instead use `Task.Run`. However, since the target member is already returning a `Task` there really is not need for `Task.Run` either

Try making the code async all the way through instead of trying to mix async and blocking code.

```
public static async Task<int> AddZoneToDbAsync(Zone zone) {
    await App.Database.SaveZoneAsync(zone);
    int zoneID = await App.Database.GetLastInsertAsync("Zone");
    return zoneID;
}
```

`GetLastInsertAsync` is not doing anything with the local variable and should be refactored to just return the task.

```
public Task<int> GetLastInsertAsync(String tablename) {
    return database.ExecuteScalarAsync<int>("SELECT last_insert_rowid() FROM " + tablename);
}
```

Reference [Async/Await - Best Practices in Asynchronous Programming](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx)

Comment: Thanks Nkosi. This didn't just help me with the project. You actually helped me understand better how to code asynchronously. I didn't realize that the await operator allowed you to get the TResult instead of the Task. Teaching myself this and it's been difficult to learn. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @TravisFleenor glad to help. You would find this article interesting Reference [Async/Await - Best Practices in Asynchronous Programming](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

**There are two problems here.**

The one that you ask for: how should I properly use async-await in this situation. And another one, one that you didn't mention: you add / update an element and ask for the ID of the last inserted Zone.

Are you absolutely certain that between your add / update and the query for the last inserted ID, no other process might have added a Zone? Do you want the Id of the Zone you just Added / Updated, or would you like the Id of the Zone that was added by the other process?

To be certain that you get the Id of the item you just added / updated it would be wise to let `database.InsertAsync` and `database.UpdateAsync` return either the complete added / updated Zone (like entity framework does) or at least return the ID of the added / updated.

These functions should be something like:

```
async Task<int> InsertAsync(Zone zone)
{
     .. // async do the insert; await until done
     int zoneId = ... // get the Id of the inserted Zone
     return zoneId;
}
```

If you can guarantee that between inserting the Zone and fetching the Id of the inserted zone no one else can interfere, it is guaranteed that you get the proper id.

**Back to your question about async-await**

Async-Await is typically used when your thread has to wait for another process to finish something: writing to a file, retrieve data from a database, fetch information from the internet. Instead of waiting, your thread could do other useful stuff.

[In this interview, Eric Lippert](https://www.i-programmer.info/professional-programmer/i-programmer/7154-c-guru-an-interview-with-eric-lippert.html?start=1) compared this with a cook making breakfast. Search somewhere in the middle for async-await. After putting up a kettle to boil the water for the tea. He doesn't wait idly. Instead he starts slicing tomatoes. When the water boils he continues making tea.

It is no use to start a new thread doing things if your thread has nothing else to do. The overhead for this will slow down the process. My advice would be to let your thread do all things using async-await. Only if your thread has to do lengthy calculations while your thread could do other useful things it can be useful to let another thread do this lengthy calculations. But if your thread has nothing else to do but wait for the results of this lengthy calculations, let your thread do this.

So my advice would be the following. Using the adjusted InsertAsync described above:

```
// Inserts / Updates Zone; returns the ID of the Saved zone
public async Task<int> SaveZoneAsync(Zone zone)
{
    if (zone.ID == 0)
    {
        int zoneId = await database.InsertAsync(zone);
        return zoneId;
    }
    else
    {
        await database.UpdateAsync(zone);
        return zone.Id;
    }
}

public static int AddZoneToDB(Zone zone)
{
    Task<int> taskSaveZone = Task.Run( () => SaveZoneAsync(zone);
    taskSaveZone.Wait();
    int zoneId = taskSaveZone.Result;
    return zoneId;

    // TODO: consider putting this all in one statement
}
```

Comment: Thanks Harold! Looking forward to taking a closer look at this when I get home. Especially your suggestion about getting the zone id in the insert/update method is very insightful and helpful. While on this local SQLite db there is no chance someone else might be entering a Zone once our API is complete and we are actually connecting to the remote db to update the Zone table the possibility another user will be entering a zone at the exact same time will be very present. Having a way to prevent any issues with concurrent updates on that table will be really important. That's great advice.

Comment: Are you sure your program can't be started twice?

Comment: Yes. Only one instance of the app will run. It's a Xamarin based mobile app. When I try to reopen it it just goes back to the existing instance.